# Javasign libraries to add to my project

Tags: java

The imports below are not resolved. I can´t find them to download in order to add them to my project.

In the project site I am able to find the program itself, not the libraries
http://javasign.sourceforge.net/index.shtml

```
import org.javasign.operators.CryptokiGenerator
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfString;
```

Does anyone knows where I can find them?

**Edit 1:**

I was able to add those libraries but there is one last issue:

error: cannot find symbol
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7;
  symbol:   class PdfPKCS7
  location: package com.itextpdf.text.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `com.lowagie.text.*` packages are from [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

`org.javasign.operators.CryptokiGenerator` is included in JavaSign itself ([download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javasign/files/)). http://javasign.sourceforge.net/docs/org/javasign/operators/CryptokiGenerator.html

Comment: Has com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7 been remove from IText package?

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo It looks like at some point that was moved to the `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security` package. http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/5740/tree/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/security/

Comment: If "The type iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.TokenException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
  required .class files" error pops up the add the following jar iaik/iaik.jar.zip and can be downloaded from java2s via http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/iaik/iaik.jar.zip

Comment: Just realized importing "iaikPkcs11Wrapper.jar" from lib folder of the javasign from sourceforge could also solve the problem